# Middleware that checks token, cannot redirect to login page

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, authentication, middleware

I am using node and express with vue. I try to implement a middleware for my node routes, to check the login token and if it is wrong, redirect to the login page.

This is my code so far.

Main `app.js` file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  

const app = express(); 

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})); 

app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
app.use('/performance', require('./routes/performance')); 

 const port = 4000;

 http.createServer(app).listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server runs on port ', port);
 });
```

Then in my routes I have

```
const express = require('express');
const token = require('../../lib/token');

router.get('/:product/dataquality/', token.validate(), (req, res)=>{   
  const product = req.params.product; 

  db.dataquality(product)
  .then((resolved)=>{   
    console.log('route dataquality result', resolved);
    res.json({success:true, data:resolved});
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log('route dataquality error', error);
    res.json({success:false, data:false});
  });
});
```

And this `token.validate` middleware is

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../db/config');
const validate = ()=>{
  return (req, res, next)=>{

    const token = req.get('Authorization');
    const key = config.key;

    jwt.verify(token, key,function(err, decoded) {
      if (err){
        console.log('token error');
        res.redirect('/login');
      } 
      if (decoded){ 
        console.log('token ok');
        next();
      } 
    });
  }
}

exports.validate = validate;
```

This works fine and I see the token console logs when I login in my app. If I go to the browser and edit the token (delete a couple of characters, but not completely remove it) so the token is there but is the wrong token, it has the wrong value : 
I see in my console `token error` and I get no data, but the redirect to login page never happens.
If I do `res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/login');` I still get no redirect.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

If you think this is a Vue issue, let me know, so I can provide Vue routing code.

Thanks

**EDIT**

This the file that handles routes in Vue - `router.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router' 
import store from '@/components/store';

import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import Performance from './views/Performance.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

const router =  new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
    },    

    {
      path: '/performance',
      name: 'performance',
      component: Performance,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => { 
        if (store.state.login.token == null || !store.state.login.token) {
          next('/login');
        }
        else{next();}
      }
    },

    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/login'
    }
  ]
})    


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.dispatch('resetAccessToken');
  if (to.fullPath === '/performance') {
    if (!store.state.login.token) {
      console.log('VUE route go to login');
      next('/login');
    }
  }
  if (to.fullPath === '/login') {
    if (store.state.login.token) {
      console.log('VUE route browse normally');
      next('/performance');
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

If I search for "route" in my browser console to find `console.log('VUE route go to login');` or `console.log('VUE route browse normally');` it says it found 160 but I cannot see none.

I still get no data, but I can browse normally to empty Vue pages. Node or Vue redirect should work and send me to login , but none works, so I still can browse around.

Thanks

Comment: Do you receive some response in Vue app? What is it? How is routing handled in Vue?

Comment: Your backend code seems okay for me. there should be an error with vue. can you please show it

Comment: @Eggon Check my post, I posted Vue routing code. What Vue data are you looking for? What should I print? Thanks

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Check my post, I posted Vue routing code. Thanks

Comment: Please post response that you receive from backend for the request with invalid credentials. I haven't used beforeEach, but it seems to me that there you are redirecting yourself to '/performance'? I mean you do still have token in store, so this condition is fulfilled?

Comment: @Eggon token.js logs `token error` when the token is invalid for now. What else should I log? - Also, yes, the routes in Vue still have a token in store, so this condition is fulfilled, but, then the token goes to the node middleware to get validated, and it fails, so the node then should redirect to login.

Comment: Are you able to redirect it via window.location.href = '/login' ??

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Wait. Replace `next('/login')`with `window.location.href = '/login' ` in vue router? What will this prove?

Comment: What is displayed in console log of the browser when you receive the response? Any errors? How do you send your request from Vue and how do you handle the reponse? Can you console.log the response? Also I had a look at beforeEach documentation and there's no such use case as you have `next('/pathName')`. It might be causing an error. Or it might be working and each time you enter `beforeEach` with `/login` path you get redirected to `/performance` route by `next('/performance');`

Comment: comment out the `next('/performance');` and try again

Comment: Also according to beforeEach documentation you should not have loose `next()` if you use ifs. Your code there should be `if (to.fullPath === '/performance') {} else if (to.fullPath === '/login') {} else next()`

Comment: @Eggon I guess the problem is that the request to the node/exprees endpoint with the broken token is send from vue using axios. So node does a re-direct but then the redirect is handled by axios inside Vue, so there is no redirect there... If I put the URL directly inside the chrome address bar, the redirect will work. If not, it will not work, because there is axios in the middle, doing the requests. So the only solution is for token.js to return an error instead of redirecting, so axios can handle that error and redirect.

Comment: 1) Do you get an error in browser console? 2) have you tried removing that "next"? 3) can you console log axios response ( axios.get('your params').then(response => {})

Comment: 1)no 2) yes and nothing changed 3) yes, but axios does not get any response due to the redirect

Comment: Ok, I don't know why this happens, it would require more trial and errors, but I can propose a workaround. From your backend do not redirect, jus send a response like this: `res.status(401).send('Invalid credentials')`. Then you can handle the response in axios and if it contains status 401 just redirect in Vuerouter inside the app.

Comment: Seems like I cannot get the axios response. I do     async fetchThings({commit}){ 
        const response = await axios.get(basicUrl+'/things' , {
            headers: {
                Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })   

        if (response) {
            console.log('ftresponse - ', response);
        }
    }
And I never see it in the browser console. How can I check it, so I can check if there is a 401 error and redirect ? Thanks

Comment: And what is logged to the console? Why do you use "if (response)" there? If nothing is looged that means there is no response? I suggest to use promise based handling. It's easier to debug. Here is a nice article about axios in vue: https://medium.com/spemer/using-axios-in-vue-js-17f186756a8b